# data added with a prepared statement can't be searched with WHERE

Tags: php, sqlite, prepared-statement, prepare

Data that I add inside an SQLite3 db using prapared statements are not searchable with WHERE:

`SELECT Active FROM Users WHERE Username="john"`

I have a demonstration in PHP that adds data with a prepared and a direct statement and then tries to search for them.

My questions are two:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I search data that I add through prepared statements?

Here is the PHP script.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki');
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$timezone = date('Z');
$db = '';

// ---

//
// adds a user in the db with a prepared statement
//

function add_user1($name, $pass)
{
    global $timezone;
    global $db;

    $time = time();

    try
    {
        $statement = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Time, Timezone, Active) VALUES     (:Username,:Password,:Time,:Timezone,:Active);";    
        $query = $db->prepare($statement);
        $query->bindValue(':Username', $name, SQLITE3_TEXT);
        $query->bindValue(':Password', $pass, SQLITE3_TEXT);
        $query->bindValue(':Time', $time, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
        $query->bindValue(':Timezone', $timezone, SQLITE3_INTEGER);
        $query->bindValue(':Active', '1', SQLITE3_INTEGER);
        $ok = $query->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}

//
// adds a user in the db with a direct execution
//

function add_user2($name, $pass)
{
    global $timezone;
    global $db;

    $time = time();

    try
    {
        $db->exec('INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Time, Timezone, Active) VALUES ("' .     $name . '", "' . $pass . '", ' . $time . ', ' . $timezone . ', 1);');
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}

//
// seeks a password for a given username
//

function seek($user)
{
    global $timezone;
    global $db;

    try
    {
        // previous tests showed that this doesn't work on all cases
        $result = $db->query('SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username="'. $user . '"');
        foreach ($result as $row)
        {
            $password = $row['Password'];
            echo "search through SQLite: password for $user is $password\n";
        }

        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Users");
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $username = $row['Username'];
            $password = $row['Password'];

            if ($username == $user)
            {
                echo " search through array: password for $username is $password";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}

// ---

echo "<pre>\n";

try
{
    $db = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                                                            $db->exec("CREATE     TABLE     IF     NOT         EXISTS         Users     (Id             INTEGER         PRIMARY     KEY,         Username     TEXT     UNIQUE     NOT NULL, Password TEXT NOT NULL, Time INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL, Timezone INTEGER NOT NULL, Active BOOLEAN NOT NULL);");
}
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}

add_user1("Bob", "cat");
sleep(1);
add_user1("Mark", "dog");
sleep(1);
add_user2("John", "mouse");
sleep(1);
add_user2("Alice", "rodent");

try
{
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Users');
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        echo "      Id: " . $row['Id'] . "\n";
        echo "Username: " . $row['Username'] . "\n";
        echo "Password: " . $row['Password'] . "\n";
        echo "    Time: " . $row['Time'] . "\n";
        echo "Timezone: " . $row['Timezone'] . "\n";
        echo "  Active: " . $row['Active'] . "\n";
        echo "\n";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}

seek("Alice");

echo "\n\n";

seek("Mark");


$db = NULL;

?>
```

Comment: I beg my pardon, it's indeed the way you described it. Moreover, when seeking using prepared statement the picture is mirrored - two other passwords found instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone told me I should remove the types on the binding. I did and it works :)

Thanks anyone who read it.

Here is the full working example.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki');
ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$timezone = date('Z');
$db = '';

// ---

//
// adds a user in the db with a prepared statement
//

function add_user1($name, $pass)
{
    global $timezone;
    global $db;

    $time = time();

    try
    {
        $statement = "INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Time, Timezone, Active)     VALUES     (:Username,:Password,:Time,:Timezone,:Active);";    
        $query = $db->prepare($statement);
        $query->bindValue(':Username', $name);
        $query->bindValue(':Password', $pass);
        $query->bindValue(':Time', $time);
        $query->bindValue(':Timezone', $timezone);
        $query->bindValue(':Active', '1');
        $ok = $query->execute();
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}

//
// adds a user in the db with a direct execution
//

function add_user2($name, $pass)
{
    global $timezone;
    global $db;

    $time = time();

    try
    {
        $db->exec('INSERT INTO Users (Username, Password, Time, Timezone, Active) VALUES ("'     .     $name . '", "' . $pass . '", ' . $time . ', ' . $timezone . ', 1);');
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}

//
// seeks a password for a given username
//

function seek($user)
{
    global $timezone;
    global $db;

    try
    {
        // previous tests showed that this doesn't work on all cases
        $result = $db->query('SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username="'. $user . '"');
        foreach ($result as $row)
        {
            $password = $row['Password'];
            echo "search through SQLite: password for $user is $password\n";
        }

        $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM Users");
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $username = $row['Username'];
            $password = $row['Password'];

            if ($username == $user)
            {
                echo " search through array: password for $username is $password";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $exception)
    {
        echo $exception->getMessage();
    }
}

// ---

echo "<pre>\n";

try
{
    $db = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                                                                                                                                                                    $db->exec("CREATE             TABLE                 IF                 NOT                         EXISTS                 Users                 (Id                 INTEGER         PRIMARY     KEY,         Username     TEXT     UNIQUE     NOT NULL, Password TEXT NOT NULL, Time INTEGER UNIQUE NOT NULL, Timezone INTEGER NOT NULL, Active BOOLEAN NOT NULL);");
}
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}

add_user1("Bob", "cat");
sleep(1);
add_user1("Mark", "dog");
sleep(1);
add_user2("John", "mouse");
sleep(1);
add_user2("Alice", "rodent");

try
{
    $result = $db->query('SELECT * FROM Users');
    foreach ($result as $row)
    {
        echo "      Id: " . $row['Id'] . "\n";
        echo "Username: " . $row['Username'] . "\n";
        echo "Password: " . $row['Password'] . "\n";
        echo "    Time: " . $row['Time'] . "\n";
        echo "Timezone: " . $row['Timezone'] . "\n";
        echo "  Active: " . $row['Active'] . "\n";
        echo "\n";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}

seek("Alice");

echo "\n\n";

seek("Mark");


$db = NULL;

?>
```